# Not getting data after dependent api call using async problem node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, nodes

I am calling API to fetch data on the basis of that data I am calling different APIs which is based on condition.

I have used a promise to maintain the async code as well but no luck so far. At the end of the block, I want every data pushed inside array but I am getting a blank array.

```
async (body, nextCall) => {
    var tmpArryOfModuleList = []
        var bodyData = body.data
        var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          bodyData.forEach(element => {
            if (element.hasCRUD === '0') {
              var options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: `${apiURL}/api/fetchAllCharts`,
                headers:
                {
                  Authorization: token
                }
              };

              request(options, function (error, response, dashboardData) {
                if (error) {
                  return nextCall({
                    error: error
                  })
                }
                var parsedDashboardData = JSON.parse(dashboardData)
                for (var i = 0; i < parsedDashboardData['data'].length; i++) {
                  var val = element.name + " - " + parsedDashboardData['data'][i]['name']
                  var randomID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
                  tmpArryOfModuleList.push({ "_id": randomID, "submodule": val })
                }
              });
            } else if (element.hasCRUD == '1') {
              var options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: `${apiURL}/api/fetchAllActions`,
                headers:
                {
                  Authorization: token
                }
              };

              request(options, function (error, response, crudData) {
                if (error) {
                  return nextCall({
                    error: error
                  })
                }
                var parsedcrudData = JSON.parse(crudData)
                for (var i = 0; i < parsedcrudData['data'].length; i++) {
                  var val = element.name + " - " + parsedcrudData['data'][i]['name']
                  var randomID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
                  tmpArryOfModuleList.push({ "_id": randomID, "submodule": val })
                }
              });
            } else {
              console.log('no data found')
              reject('No Data Found')
            }
          })
          resolve(tmpArryOfModuleList)
        })
        console.log('tmpArryOfModuleList', tmpArryOfModuleList)
      }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the result on the last array?

Comment: I think you need to use the promise, like: let tmpArryOfModuleList = await promise()

Comment: @madprops didn't get you

Comment: I think you are just declaring the promise and not using it. Google around to see how you can use promises.

Comment: @madprops I have tried promise.then(data => {
          console.log("promise data", data)
        })

still no luck

Comment: Are you using the .then after/outside the promise declaration?

Comment: @madprops Yes!!

Comment: I think there's some things wrong with your code apart from the promise part. I don't know if  you're declaring the tmpArray somewhere else but it's not declared in the promise. Also the request operations are asynchronous I think, so you'd have to deal with those too, because the promise would resolve before they're finished.

Comment: @madprops I have decared it here now async (body, nextCall) => {
        var tmpArryOfModuleList = []

Comment: How can I achieve this ?

Comment: the problem with where you're calling `resolve` is, that the asynchronous `request`'s won't have even started before youy resolve - you're also tagging the function `async` when you don't even use await, so there's no need for that at all

Comment: @JaromandaX I have removed async. When can I resolve it and how can I ? example would be great.

Comment: what is the purpose of nextCall? why do you call nextCall **instead** of resolving or rejecting, that would leave a permanently pending Promise

Comment: After I fetch data I will send it to next function and from there I will send it to front(API). I am using waterfall.

Comment: I will send constructed array.

Comment: "waterfall" ... so that's asyncjs?

Comment: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall refer this